# Copy Shape Keys AND Shape Key Keyframes to Another (Identical) Mesh

Tags: keyframes, shape-keys

i need to do this in 2.79 (because reasons), but am willing to look at methods for any/all versions.

i have a weight-painted mesh object with shape keys.  the shape keys are keyframed.

the setup i'm working with deletes all my shape keys on my mesh when i bind it to a new rig (because reasons.  i can't change/fix this.)

AT ANY RATE...

i need to

A:  copy all the shapekeys from one mesh to an identical mesh.  i found a way to do that, one by one.  is there a FASTER way?  (i also have an addon that copies all shape keys from UNidentical meshes, but even that's not working right in this instance.)

B:  copy all the shapekey KEYFRAMES to this new mesh.  or move them?  because i cannot figure out how.

i saw on this question
[Efficient way to programmatically copy shape key animation from one mesh to another](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242890/efficient-way-to-programmatically-copy-shape-key-animation-from-one-mesh-to-anot)

"And it's even faster to just copy an action and rename the keyblocks its fcurves target."

but no indication HOW you do this maneuver.

well, it says 'copy an action.'  however, these shapekey keyframes are not on any action that i can find in the action editor.  they ONLY appear in the dope sheet.  they are named "Key.000" and i can't seem to do anything with that section.  i can't drag anywhere, i can't rename, i can't right click because nothing happens...

https://prnt.sc/L-h_2iEZLYrf

in image:
Yellow Arrows:  shape keys on active mesh, shape key keyframes on Key.000 under active mesh

Orange Arrows:  channel for selected mesh, w/o shape keys or keyframes

Red Arrow: what i want to move from one mesh to the other.

you can see in the lower action editor, there is NO action named Key.000 for me to find and 'copy'  :/

Comment: maybe copy means Ctrl L > Link Animation Data, then be sure to make animation Single User... could do the same to copy mesh data with shapekeys but only if both objects are identical