# Populating Fcurves Keyframe_Points

Tags: python, keyframes, shape-keys, fcurves, actions

I am currently working on an importer for captured Shape Key motions. To fasten up the process, I am using the method [suggested here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/editing-fcurve-keyframe-points-in-fast-mode). It works perfectly and saves up to a few minutes per import.

I am confused about the way the keyframes are displayed in the viewport.
The keyframes show up in the Graph Editor and Dopesheet (Shape Key Editor view) like this:

[image]

Here is what I am doing:

```py
if object_with_shape_keys:

    keyblocks = object_with_shape_keys.data.shape_keys.key_blocks

    for i, key in enumerate(keyblocks):

        if i == 0:
            continue
        # values captured in nano seconds:
        values = self.get_values_for_animation(shape_key_animation_values, frame_count, index = i-1)

        dp = 'key_blocks["{}"].value'.format(key.name)

        fc = self.get_fcurve(mocap_action, data_path = dp) or None

        # When there is no fcurve existing for that datapath,
        # then we can simply create a new one and populate it
        if not fc:

            fc = mocap_action.fcurves.new(dp, index = i)

            # Create new keyframe points and populate captured values
            fc.keyframe_points.add(count = frame_count)
            fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set('co', [x for co in zip(frames, values) for x in co])
```

The issue I am having with it is that the keyframes do not show up in the data tab in the object properties and I cannot get them to show up. It looks like this:

[image]

When I manually add a keyframe to one of the Shape Keys then I the interface looks like this:

[image]

What's worse is that after manually adding a keyframe, the previously working motion is overwritten for that specific Shape Key...

To summarize: There is a discrepancy between the keyframe_points stored in the individual fcurves and the keyframes displayed in the viewport. I am wondering if I am missing something or if this is intended behavior. I hope I made myself clear!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce, can you give more details? This is what I'm doing: https://pastebin.com/GG3rue3u

Comment: Hey scurest, thanks a lot for taking a shot at this.. I edited the question to include a snippet. The issue did not arise in your example, so it must be something I am doing in my script. The animation itself is working as it should. Worth noting that the data I am using is captured in nano seconds range which results in many subframes. I tried verifying this by modifying your example to subframes, but it still worked as expected... Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```py
fc = mocap_action.fcurves.new(dp, index = i)
```

Delete `index = i`.

That sets `fc.array_index` which is for things like locations (index=0 targets X, 1 targets Y, etc.). You don't need it for shape keys.

Comment: Thank you! That was easier than expected! :)